# Regex Javascript matching all

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
var str='[match1] text [match2] [match3] text';
```

I need all the words enclosed by []

the result should be `match1, match2,match3`

I tried `str.match(/\[([^]]+)\]/);` what would be the correct Regex?

Comment: Why does your character set match everything but `}` instead of everything but `]`?

Comment: that's a typo. fixed it

Comment: Missing the `g` flag?

Comment: tried escaping ] ? ([^\\]]+) or is it the auto-formatting that hid it away? (like it just did to me, had to put two \ to display 1)

Answer (score 1):

```
str.match(/[^\[\]]+(?=])/g)
```

should do it when `[` and `]` pair properly and don't nest.

You need to match the right kind of brackets and use the `g` flag to make the regexp global so that it returns all matches.

Also, I used a lookahead to identify the end of a bracketed group because match will return the entire matched text, not a captured group.

---

```
var str='[match1] text [match2] [match3] text';
str.match(/[^\[\]]+(?=])/g)
```

yields

```
["match1","match2","match3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.match(/[^[]+?(?=\])/g);
```

This will match on the brackets, but create captures without the brackets.  +? Lazy quantifier will  only get the stuff inside of each [] pair.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
str.match(/\[[^ \]]+]/g)
```